# import openai as OpenAI

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, openaiembeddings

I am having trouble importing openai in the latest version -

```
$ pip3.11 install openai
Requirement already satisfied: openai in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distro<2,>=1.7.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from openai) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: anyio<5,>=3.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from openai) (3.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: httpx<1,>=0.23.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from openai) (0.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions<5,>=4.7 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from openai) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from openai) (4.64.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from openai) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic<3,>=1.9.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from openai) (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.8 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from anyio<5,>=3.5.0->openai) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from httpx<1,>=0.23.0->openai) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: httpcore==1.* in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from httpx<1,>=0.23.0->openai) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic-core==2.16.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pydantic<3,>=1.9.0->openai) (2.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: annotated-types>=0.4.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pydantic<3,>=1.9.0->openai) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h11<0.15,>=0.13 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from httpcore==1.*->httpx<1,>=0.23.0->openai) (0.14.0)
```

Latest version of Open AI is installed

Still - I get this error

```
$ python3.11
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct 23 2023, 22:47:21) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> from openai import OpenAI
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'
>>> from openai import OpenAI
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'
```

Comment: You've got some kind of config screwed up that's causing `pip3.11` to look in Python 3.8 directories. (It's possible that you might even have aliased `pip3.11` to a Python 3.8 pip, though we can't tell exactly what's going on.)

Answer (score 1):

create a new python environment may be using conda then try installing openai and import it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35733471)